# Show that $n^2 + n$ is divisible by 2 for all natural numbers n via **inductive proof**

Tags: proof-writing, induction

> Show that $n^2 + n$ is divisible by 2 for all natural numbers n via **inductive proof**

I was wondering how to approach this problem via the usage of inductive proofs, my thoughts on this problem was to show that the MOD 2 of all the numbers were going to be 0 but I did not know how to show this in my proof and I was wondering on how to do it.

Another way I thought of doing was to change  $n^2 + n$  into a form that has 2 multiplying an expression but I also didn't know how to do this as well.

But I also do appreciate other methodologies in doing so and thus I request for assistance

Comment: If it's an inductive prove, then you want to prove $(n+1)^2 + (n+1) = n^2 + n \pm 2K$ for some $K$.

Comment: @fleablood I am very new to inductive proofs, can you explain why there is the 2k? because what if $n^2+n$ is actually an odd number?

Comment: If $n= 1$ then $n^2 + n = 2$ is even.  Then for any case were $n^2 + n$ is even (such as when $n=1$) show that in *those* cases (don't worry about the cases where $n^2 +n$ are odd; we are proving for the cases where it is even that *THE NEXT CASE* will be even) that $(n+1)^2 + (n+1)$ is also even.  Then by inductive logic if 1) the first case if even and 2) for every even case, the *next* case is even then 3) we must conclude *all* cases are even.

Comment: @JohnRawls That is why we assume it to be a multiple of 2 in our assumptive step. See my proof below for how we use it. The principle of induction involves assuming the statement to be true for a certain integer and showing that $if$ it is true for one integer, it is true for the next. Having proved it is true for 1, we can then use our inductive step to say it is true for 2, and then 3, and then 4, ..., and then all natural numbers $n$

Comment: Proving this inductively is silly but I guess it's a good exercise in learning induction.

Comment: Base case: $n=1$ then $n^2 + n = 1^2 + 1 = 2$ is even.  Inductive step:  $(n+1)^2 + (n+1) = (n^2 + n) + 2(n+1)$ so if $n^2 + n$ is even then $(n+1)^2 + (n+1)$ is even.  If $n^2 + n$ is odd then $(n+1)^2 + (n+1)$ is odd.  Inductive logic:The first case, n=1 is even.  So the next case and all subsequence cases are even.  So they are all even.

Comment: In a prove by induction you show physically that at least *one* case exists.  Then you show that if one case exists, it must follow that the next case exists.  Then by bootstrapping and repeating an infinite number of times all cases exist.  We don't assume that *all* n^2 + n are even, we just assume that we know *one* case is even.  And we *do* know that as $n=1$ makes an even case.  We don't have to worry about $n^2 + n$ being odd, as we'll just take another (n=1) where it is even instead.

Comment: This is a two-liner: $$ \left[(n+1)^2+(n+1)\right]-\left[n^2+n\right] = 2(n+1) $$ is clearly even and $n^2+n$ is clearly even for $n=0$ or $n=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induction on positive integers $n$:

- When $n=1$, $n^2 + n = 2$ which is obviously divisible by 2.
- Assume when $n=k$, that $k^2 + k$ is divisible by 2.
- When $n=k+1$, we have $$(k+1)^2 + k+1 = k^2 + 2k + 1 + k + 1 $$$$= (k^2 + k) + 2(k+1)$$ From our assumption, $k^2+k$ is divisible by 2 and so the whole expression is divisible by 2.

Therefore, by induction, $n^2+n$ is divisible by 2 for all natural numbers $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  $(n+1)^2 + (n+1) = n^2 + 2n + 1 + n + 1 = n^2 + n + 2n+ 2= (n^2 + n) + 2(n+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $n^2 + n = 2k$ for some integer $k$ (which is true for base case $n=0$) we wish to show that $(n+1)^2 + (n+1) = 2j$ for some integer $j$.

And $(n+1)^2 + (n+1) = n^2 + n + 2n + 2 = 2k + 2n + 2 = 2(k+n+1) = 2j$